# AJAX returning included files from Classic ASP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp-classic

I have an application which is using AJAX and Classic ASP, in my ajax request I am trying to return a JSON value from the page.

```
$("#btnSaveAdvisor").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "verify_survey.asp",
        contentType: "application/text",
        dataType: "text",
        data: { 
        }, success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, error : function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
```

(I Removed the data parameters because there were loads)

I am fetching it as a dataType of text, but when set to JSON it is returning the same thing. The problem is that the return data is:

```
<!-- include file="functions/tabs/tabs.asp" -->


<!-- include file="functions/password/config_password.asp" -->


[{"surveyId" : "64"}]
```

However, when I pass the parameters into the URL, it only shows the last line.

When I add this

```
Response.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

It returns all the lines I see above, hwo can I make it so these two lines don't appear when I'm not even writing them to the page?

Comment: Note: When you pass the parameter in the URL, the page will be interpreted as an HTML page by your browser.  That means the any content between `<!--` and  `-->` will not render on the page.  However, if you view source - you'll see that same thing you posted above.

Comment: Your problem is in the ASP code that's returning this data, not your jQuery code.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much, however I am editing a very old piece of code and it's got a lot of code to it, so don't want to just go removing pieces of code, what I did do however was add some unique characters around the JSON and in the JavaScript got all the content between the unique characters to get it working

Comment: So what is returns is basically something like [\/{"json":"1"}\/], it's not a good way to do it but it works, but would of liked to find a more better solution

Answer (score 0):

Those two statements at some point have been valid IIS Server Side Include Directives *(SSI)* but probably as a hack to stop them being processed the `#` was removed.

The problem with this is they are no longer pre-processed and treated like any other output being outputted with the rest of the page when it is called by the client *(as [@technophobia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984275/technophobia) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220269/ajax-returning-included-files-from-classic-asp#comment48545345_30220269) in the comments)*.

So to stop these appearing you have a couple of choices;

1. Add the `#` and allow the SSIs to be pre-processed.
2. Remove the `<!-- include -->` lines completely, as they do not contain the `#include` they are not being pre-processed anyway. *(recommended)*
3. Conditionally load the SSIs, something like;

   ```vb
   <% 
   Dim process_includes

   'Pass querystring value to determine if includes are processed.
   process_includes = (Request.QueryString("i") = "1")
   If process_includes Then
   %><!-- #include file="functions/tabs/tabs.asp" -->
   <!-- #include file="functions/password/config_password.asp" --><%
   End If
   %>
   ```

   then you can modify the AJAX

   to process the includes;

   ```js
   url: "verify_survey.asp?i=1"
   ```

   or to ignore them;

   ```js
   url: "verify_survey.asp?i=0"
   ```

   > Bear in mind that this method will give different results depending on how the includes are organised. If the includes contain a list of functions this method is not suited as `Function` or `Sub` statements can't exists inside an `If` statement.
   >
   > But then you have to ask yourself, *if it is just a list of `Function` and/or `Sub` procedures what is the harm in leaving it to be pre-processed in the first place?*